# Discord.js ReferenceError: embed is not defined

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm new to coding so I decided to make a discord bot that sends memes from Reddit. but whenever I send the command it gives me the error and crashes the bot. what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it

here's all of the discord bot

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const randomPuppy = require('random-puppy');
const prefix = '%'

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('CounterOutplayer is READY!');
});

module.exports = {
    name: "meme",
    description: "Random image from a specific subreddit",
    async run (client, message, args){
        const subReddits = ["memes", "dankmemes"]
        const random = subReddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * subReddits.length)]

        const img = await randomPuppy(random);

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("Green")
        .setImage(img)
        .setTitle(`memes - ${random}`)
        .setURL(`https://reddit.com/r/${random}`)

        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
}


client.login('token')
```

Comment: What line is the error occurring on?

Comment: What is the error? (Edit your op with a screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending just a string, you can just use `message.channel.send('TEXT')`. For an embed, that belongs in the "options" parameter of the [`.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) function; so, you'll have to send it as an object. In other words, use `message.channel.send({ embed: embed })`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `.setColor("Green")` is making the embed go undefined. According to the discord.js docs, color options are either a number, a hex code like `#00ff00`, an RGB array like `[0, 255, 0]`, or a color string. You have "Green" in your code, but the docs list out valid colors and all of them are caps. `.setColor("GREEN")` should work just fine.